# Union of convex hulls

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{C}(A) \cup \mathcal{C}(B)) = \mathcal{C}(A \cup B)$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $\mathcal{C}(A \cup B) \subseteq \mathcal{C}(\mathcal{C}(A)\cup\mathcal{C}(B))$ since $A \cup B \subseteq \mathcal{C}(A)\cup\mathcal{C}(B)$.

Conversely, $\mathcal{C}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{C}(A \cup B) $, and $\mathcal{C}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{C}(A \cup B)$ (since $A,B \subseteq A \cup B$). So $\mathcal{C}(A)\cup\mathcal{C}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{C}(A \cup B)$. Finally, applying $\mathcal{C}$ you get

$$\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{C}(A)\cup\mathcal{C}(B)) \subseteq \mathcal{C} (\mathcal{C} (A \cup B)) = \mathcal{C}(A \cup B)$$

Comment: Big thanks, I did something similar, but mixed up something. Now it's clear!

Answer (score 1):

Use that $\mathcal C$ is *monotone*, that is for $X \subseteq Y$ you have $\mathcal C (X) \subseteq \mathcal C (Y)$.